# Can't reach default gateway in wireless connection on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

This problem is local to a specific laptop. Similar setup works fine on many other laptops.

I have a wireless network at my workplace I can't get my laptop to talk to it. The connection to the network happens successfully, but after it happens, no traffic can go in or out. I do not know the server configuration and I'm unable to get support from that end.

On the laptop:

- Windows 7 Home Premium
- No firewall is installed
- Windows firewall is stopped
- Ipv6 is disabled
- Homegroup is disabled

Once I connected to the network I get the following ipconfig /all readings:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Alienware
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : mobile.local

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C0-CB-38-39-55-13
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 5C-AC-4C-E7-CA-CB
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : DOMAIN.co.nz
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Atheros AR8132 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 5C-26-0A-17-B7-D4
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : mobile.local
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : DW1520 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C0-CB-38-39-55-13
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.26.77.32(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.252.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, 27 September 2011 12:57:14 p.m.
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, 27 September 2011 8:57:13 p.m.
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.26.76.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 1.1.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : DNS_SERVER_1
                                       DNS_SERVER_2
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{205B67BC-F0F7-46A8-B0E8-563802A2BA90}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.mobile.local:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.DOMAIN.co.nz:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{F921E69B-CEB5-4450-B837-20C031DACEBE}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Here is the route print data:

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 16...c0 cb 38 39 55 13 ......Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
 13...5c ac 4c e7 ca cb ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
 11...5c 26 0a 17 b7 d4 ......Atheros AR8132 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller
 10...c0 cb 38 39 55 13 ......DW1520 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 18...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 20...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 19...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
 33...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
 14...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      172.26.76.1     172.26.77.32     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      172.26.76.0    255.255.252.0         On-link      172.26.77.32    281
     172.26.77.32  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.26.77.32    281
    172.26.79.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.26.77.32    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      172.26.77.32    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.26.77.32    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

And this is the result of pinging default gateway:

```
Pinging 172.26.76.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 172.26.76.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

The wireless connection level is strong.

Could you please help me troubleshoot this issue?

**Update 1**

Output of arp -a right after pinging the default gateway:

```
Interface: 172.26.77.32 --- 0xa
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  172.26.79.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static    
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static    
  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static    
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static    
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
```

Comment: Did you obfuscate the DHCP and DNS servers in the wireless ipconfig? If not, then the 1.1.1.1 suggests a catch-and-release wireless connection like you would find at a hotel. This would require going to a website and getting redirected to a login page.  If you ping google.com does it resolve?

Comment: @Paul: I did obfuscate DNS servers but not the DHCP server it really reads 1.1.1.1. Nothing pings and nothing resolves. I can't ping the dns servers, can't ping google.com neither by ip nor by name. Can ping myself, but that's about it.

Comment: Ok, can you trying pinging the default gateway, then immediately do an ```arp -a``` and see if you get a MAC address (as opposed to incomplete) for the gateway IP.

Comment: @Paul output of arp -a does not have the gateway IP in it. I'll post the output shortly. It has an IP that starts like the gateway IP but has different ending.

Comment: @Paul: posted the output from arp -a at the end of the question

Comment: The different ending one is the broadcast address for the network, and is correct.  That there is no entry for the .1 suggests that Windows did not even attempt an arp request (to determine the MAC of the gateway).  I can't think of any reason why it would not do this, so perhaps it just isn't reporting the results.  If I was at the machine I would be digging out wireshark and seeing exactly what was going on on the interface.

Comment: @Paul, good advice. I'll try and see if I can make sense of whatever I can see in wireshark.

Comment: @Paul, in wireshark I see an ARP broadcast for default gateway IP every few seconds and nothing else at all.

Comment: Yes, sorry, my mistake, Windows doesn't list anything in arp if it didn't get a reply.  So the gateway is not responding to arp, which means it isn't on the same broadcast domain as you.  I think you are going to have to take this to your network admins to figure out why.